# Java reflection can't instantiate a private nested class with no arg constructor

Tags: java, reflection, constructor

I need to create an instance of a `private static class` which doesn't have a constructor (only the default no-arg constructor). The class is located in a 3d party library.

However, `Class.getDeclaredConstructors()` returns an empty list for some reason. I created a sample with a `private static class` within the same codebase, and in this case `Class.getDeclaredConstructors()` returned a list with 1 constructor (the default one) as expected.

Also calling `Class.newInstance()` directly results in an exception like

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessException: java.lang.Class<MyClassA> is not accessible from java.lang.Class<MyClassB>
```

What might be the reason for this strange behavior? Are there any other ways to instantiate a `private static class` without non-default constructors?

Comment: please share the code instead of text explaining it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, I'm trying to do this on Android API 32 and this probably has to do with [these limitations](https://developer.android.com/guide/app-compatibility/restrictions-non-sdk-interfaces).